# How to ensure that winkey + P (Project) has a display option selected and not the back button

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

I have two PCs connected to two screens of different dimensions.
Depending on what work I am doing, I have PC A connected to screen1 only, screen2 only, or both screens (via a DP connector). PC B is normally only connected to screen1 when used (USB-C connector).

My issue is: If I forget to select screen2 as the primary before shutting down PC A, sometimes the <kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> option selects the back arrow, instead of one of the screen options. in older versions of windows, repeated presses of <kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> would cycle though the display options.

This extra menu frustrates me several times a week. I sometimes resort to unplugging the unused screen from PC A, but I have plans to reposition this PC so that will become less feasible.

Any suggested alternative?

[image: winkey project menu]

Comment: Do you mean that repeated Win+P no longer cycles thru all options in your case?

Comment: not if the back arrow is selected for some reason. really irritating when you cannot see what is going on on the screen

Comment: Does Tab work ?

Comment: maybe that is part of the issue - <kbd>tab</kbd> switches between the back button, the setting and the more settingss button

Comment: And switching the focus to another window and back? Clicking an entry?

Comment: @harrymc I would be clicking randomly - when i switch screens the whole issue is that this sometimes comes up on the monitor which is switched to USB-C - I think the root issue is that since the monitor is turned on - the PC sees it as present.